# Create custom tab automatically in a Git Repo on creation

Tags: github, github-api

Is there a way to create a custom tab automatically every time a repo is created?

PS: I tried using the repo template to create a repo, but that can only mimic the structure of a repo while creating a new repository and does not mimic the tabs. In my use case I need to insert a backend identifier while Github repo is being created (for e.g.: a unique ID), which can be later fetched via API.

One way I thought of doing this is via custom tabs, however not sure how can I ask users to fill in custom tab information on the repo creation itself.

Is there a better way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "tab"? The word can refer to the TAB key on the keyboard, or tabs in tabbed browsers, but neither of those seems to fit here.

Comment: Added image of tabs here for e.g.: you see code, issues etc. tab in repo view.

Comment: Ah. I don't believe there is, but if there is a way, it's exclusive to GitHub.